# Adding a subview to UITableCellView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I want to add a subview to the `UITableCellView` class. However, non of the provided views in the class seem to be able to do exactly what I was looking for.

I basically want to add my own background view, filling the whole cell. However, if I replace the `backgroundView`, the style from the grouped table view layout isn't displayed anymore. If I add a subview to `backgroundView`, the subview is not shown at all. If I add a subview to the `contentView`, I can't draw behind the accessory icon.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can't change the backgorund of GroupedTable View.

Try using it with PlainTable.

and add the your backgroung image (of size = cellsize) to cellforRowAtIndex method.

Comment: I'm going with this idea for now. Not ideal, but the quickest and cleanest solution that I found so far.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at this article:

["Easy custom UITableView Drawing"](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html)

In particular:

> First: the UITableView does not itself
>   draw anything except the background.
>   To customize the background of a
>   UITableView, all you need to do is set
>   its backgroundColor to [UIColor
>   clearColor] and you can draw your own
>   background in a view behind the
>   UITableView.

Comment: That's not exactly what I was looking for. I only want to customise one UITableCellView, not the whole table. The article is suggesting to use custom background images for every cell. That's going to be a pain if I want to support different orientations on both iPad/iPhone...

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the custom view as part of your contentView.  Set a unique reuse identifier for that cell, configure it when you create it and from then on simply reset the data components (this is easiest to do if you create a custom cell controller class so that it can track all the parts and use setters/getters for the data).